# ListView header doesn't scroll

Tags: android

I implemented a `listView` with header.

However when I scroll on the header layout the page doesn't scroll down (the scroll doesn't scroll the page down).

However, when I scroll on the `listView` (which located on the bottom of the header layout) the page scroll down and also the header disappear (as expected).

Can I implement that when I scroll down the header layout, the page will `scroll` `down` to the `listView`?

Here is my code:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.freinds_listview_header, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.freind_header_layout_root));
        listView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
```

Comment: Header will scroll by default for listview

Comment: this is not what a ListView header is supposed to do, you are looking for a view that will not be attached to the list and will stay in the same location all the time. try a view that's not connected to the ListView

Comment: @thepoosh, i didnt understand you, can you give me an example? thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```
    LayoutInflater inflater; = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.freinds_listview_header, null);
    listView.addHeaderView(header);
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: thanks i tried, however it gives me the same result as before ( i still cant scroll the header layout)

Comment: you want the listview header to be scrolled with your listview content?

Comment: yes, when i scroll the listView down, the header layout will disappear and only the listView will be shown (when i scroll up again to the top, it will show the header layout again). However, now when i scroll on the header layout it doesnt scroll down, only when scroll on the listView

Comment: Ok, So you want your header to be appeared either you move the list up or down?

Comment: no, i want a header view like in the facebook app, the profile picture and name are scroll down when i scroll the page down...i want here the same..when i scroll down  i want that the header view will disappear and will only show the listview

Answer (score -1):

the ListView header is not supposed to float with the data on scroll, meaning, by definition, the header view stays and the top of the list like a special first row to the list.

if you want to create a floating View that scrolls down with the user as he scrolls the list, you should create it in the layout next to the list view like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/headerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/my_background_image" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: hi, however in your layout when i scroll down the list the hedaer layout doesnt diappear.. i want that the header_layout will disappear when i scroll down the list and when the user scroll up again the header will be visible...